# `np.average()` format option

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to understand a python code, a specific line of the code has troubled me a bit:

```
mean = np.average(data[:,index])
```

I understand that this is an average calculation of `data` declared early above, but what does `[:,index]`indicate?
I apologise if this question is duplicated, but please link me a solution before you mark it down. This is the first day I'm exposed to Python, please excuse my ignorance. Appreciate for any kind advice!
  below is part of the original code

```
data = np.genfromtxt(args.inputfile)

def doBlocking(data,index):
ndata = data.shape[0]       
ncols = data.shape[1]-1
#things unimportant
mean = np.average(data[:,index])
#more unimportance
```

Comment: To the person who voted me down: It may be a trivial question to an experienced Python user, but I have explained clearly that this is my first-time exposure to Python, and what have you contributed here in contrast? People who tried to help here at least deserved some credit, please be respectful!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In this case `data` is a two dimensional `numpy.array`. `Numpy` supports slicing similar to that of `Matlab`

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: data = np.arange(15)

In [3]: data
Out[3]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14])

In [4]: data = data.reshape([5,3])

In [5]: data
Out[5]:
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
   [ 3,  4,  5],
   [ 6,  7,  8],
   [ 9, 10, 11],
   [12, 13, 14]])

In [6]: data[:, 1]
Out[6]: array([ 1,  4,  7, 10, 13])
```

As you can see it selects the second column

Your code above will get the mean of column `index`. It basically says "Compute the mean for data in every line, and column `index`"

Comment: Hi @Andrew, first of all, thanks for the quick responses. But I'm still not quite certain about this index, within my code
    
     data = np.genfromtxt(args.inputfile) 
     def doBlocking(data,index):
        ndata = data.shape[0]
        ncols = data.shape[1] -1
         #something unimportant here
        mean = np.average(data[:,index])

Comment: And thanks also goes to @kameranis 

above is part of the original code, it is obvious to see that `data` is the import of the inputfile, if my understanding serves me right, this `index` is a specific column of variables within the inputfile data, please do correct me if I'm wrong?

sorry, I passed the characters limit, which is why I posted separately, excuse me

Comment: it seems it wasn't formatted appropriately, let me update this in the original question

Comment: As you can see it is just a handy way to select parts of your numpy array

Answer (score 0):

It is so called slicing. In your case average of specific column (with index equal to variable with the name "index") of 2-dimensional array is calculated.

Comment: Also, I have just quickly checked Python slice notation for the sake of my own curiosities, the presence of `,` comma is missing in all the examples I've found, I wonder what does the comma do in this case?

Comment: This is a feature from numpy package. Please, look at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/user/basics.indexing.html for more detailed explanations.